# Upload image from outside of webroot in webroot folder

Tags: php, file-upload, directory-structure

I have folder structure like this

```
public_html
     /images

outside
    /file_uploader.php
```

that is, `public_html` is webroot folder.

`outside` is outside of webroot folder.

So, I want upload file in folder  `public_html/images`.

I have in file `outside/file_uploader.php`  this code:

```
move_uploaded_file(
     $_FILES['img_name']['tmp_name'], 
     absolute/path/to/public_html/images/folder
);
```

But this returns error, that `Unable to access to public_html/images` folder.

Question: how can upload file from `outside_of_webroot_file` in `webroot\folder` ?

Comment: This is problem with file system rights. If you on linux take a look if web user has rights to write in folder "images"

Answer (score 0):

```
// see if you have permission to write to this folder
if(!is_writable(absolute/path/to/..)) {
    chmod()
}

move_uploaded_file()
```